# Comprehensive Sickness Insurance (CSI)

Tags: resident-permit, eu-spouses, health-insurance

I'm 65, a UK citizen, married to a non-EU citizen.
We have just returned to the UK following a period in Spain and intend for her to apply for a UKRC soon under Surinder Singh provisions.
My question concerns CSI for her. I will be self-sufficient ( private and state pensions) so reading the rules it seems clear that CSI will be required.
However, as I'm over the age where NI contributions are required, what would happen if I set up as self-employed? Would that negate the CSI requirement for her and would I still need to make NI contributions given my comment about age above?